# Mocking in Behave and Flask

Tags: python, flask, bdd, python-mock, python-behave

I am trying to mock an HTTP request call using mock because I don't want to `Behave` to call it actually.

So I have this code scenario in `matches.py` file:

```py
import request

def get_match():
   response = request.get("https://example.com")
   return response
```

And in my step definition `match_steps.py` for behave I have this:

```py
def logoport_matches_response(context):
   mock_response = context.text # this is the payload will come from feature file
   with patch ('match') as mock_match:
      mock_match.get_match.return_value = {"status": "success"}
```

But it seems this is not working because it still requesting an actual HTTP request.

I need to mock the `get_match` method to return `{"status": "success"}` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figure it out, you need to put your initialization inside the mock so:

```py
from mock import patch
from matches import get_match


with patch ('match') as mock_match:
      mock_match.return_value = {"status": "success"}
      get_match()
```